# create XML file using minidom

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I supposed to create a xml file using python in the below format ,

```
<datasource formatted-name='federated' inline='true'>
  <connection class='federated'>
    <named-connections>
      <named-connection caption='Sample - Superstore' name='excel.1ew9u4t0tggb9315darmm0nfz2kb'>
        <connection class='excel' driver='' header='yes' imex='1' password='' server='' />
      </named-connection>
    </named-connections>
  </connection>
</datasource>
```

i tried with minidom

```py
from xml.dom import minidom 
import os  

root = minidom.Document() 
  
xml = root.createElement('Datasource')  
root.appendChild(xml) 
  
productChild = root.createElement('Connection') 
productChild.setAttribute('name', 'Federated') 
xml.appendChild(productChild) 

productChild1 = root.createTextNode('named-connections') 
productChild2=root.createElement('named-connection')
productChild2.setAttribute('name', 'caption=SampleSuperstore')
xml.appendChild(productChild1)
  
xml_str = root.toprettyxml(indent ="\t")  
  
save_path_file = "gfg.xml"
  
with open(save_path_file, "w") as f: 
    f.write(xml_str)
```

I'm getting only this

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Database>
    <Connection name="Federated"/>
    named-connections
</Database>
```

i don't know how to create a child node inside `<named-connections>`. Can someone help??

Thanks,
Aarush

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing. I kept searching and found an answer. In case someone else needs the same info:

```
root = minidom.Document() 
 
xml = root.createElement('Datasource')  
root.appendChild(xml) 

productChild = root.createElement('connection')
productChild.setAttribute('formatted-name', 'Federated') 
productChild.setAttribute('inline', 'true') 
xml.appendChild(productChild)

# named-connections indent
childOfProduct = root.createElement('named-connections')
productChild.appendChild(childOfProduct)

# named-connection indent
productChild1 = root.createElement('named-connection')
productChild1.setAttribute('caption', 'Sample - Superstore')
productChild1.setAttribute('name', 'excel.1ew9u4t0tggb9315darmm0nfz2kb')
childOfProduct.appendChild(productChild1)

# connection indent
productChild2 = root.createElement('connection')
productChild2.setAttribute('class', 'excel')
productChild2.setAttribute('driver', '')
productChild2.setAttribute('header', 'yes')
productChild2.setAttribute('imex', '1')
productChild2.setAttribute('password', '')
productChild2.setAttribute('server', '')
productChild1.appendChild(productChild2)
```

Sorry if something is wrong, i am not a pro though.
Hope this helps future searchers.